# How to run Elixir from a thumb drive and without batch file launchers?

Tags: erlang, elixir, usb-drive

I have Erlang and Elixir installed on my thumb drive. The launcher for Elixir is a Windows Batch file rather than a standalone executable.

One of the computers that I use regularly for school blocks the command prompt, but Erlang runs without command prompt, so I am able to use Erlang on the school computer.

I was wondering if I could run Elixir manually or potentially with PowerShell, so that I could code at school.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the bottom of the batch file](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/bin/elixir.bat#L131) you'll see that elixir.bat is just building up an argument string to use when invoking the Erlang executable. You can just build the argument string by hand, and if you launch Erlang correctly you'll be in Elixir-land.

Alternatively, if you can run any executable, maybe you should try putting a copy of PowerShell on your thumb drive.